# Prove somebody knows everybody if any 2 people know at least one third person with whom they are both friends

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have a group of 5 people with the property that any 2 people know at least one third person with whom they are both friends. Show that there is someone who is friends with everybody.

Answer (score 2):

We can draw a graph with five vertices, say $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$, representing the people, and an edge between any pair that are friends.  We want to show that if every pair of vertices have a common neighbour, then there is a vertex of degree $4$.

So how do we show this?  Well first note that every vertex must have positive degree, since it has to have common neighbours with every other vertex.  In fact, there cannot even be a vertex of degree $1$: suppose $b$ was the only neighbour of $a$.  Then $a$ and $b$ do not have any common neighbours, which contradicts the assumption.  Hence every vertex has degree at least $2$.

Suppose now $a$ had degree exactly $2$, and without loss of generality, suppose its only neighbours are $b$ and $c$.  The only possible common neighbour of $a$ and $b$ is $c$, which means $b$ and $c$ are friends.  This means $b$ and $c$ each already have at least two neighbours: $a$ and each other.

But now the other two vertices, $d$ and $e$, have to have a common neighbour.  It cannot be $a$, since $a$ is not a neighbour of either.  Hence it has to be either $b$ or $c$.  Without loss of generality, suppose it is $b$.  This means that $b$ has degree $4$, as required.

Hence we are done if there is a vertex of degree less than $3$.  Suppose the minimum degree was $3$.  By the Handshake Lemma, there can only be an even number of vertices of odd degree.  Hence there must be a vertex of even degree, which would then have to be $4$, and we would again be done.

This means that if every pair of the five vertices has a common neighbour, there is some vertex of degree $4$.

Answer (score 1):

You must have at least two people friends with each other. x, y are both friends z so x and z as well as y and z are friends.

Call these two friends A and B.  A and B must both be friends with a third person.  Call that C.  A, B, and C are mutual friends.

Call the remaining two people D and E.  D and E must know a third person in common and that person must be one of A,B or C.  That one person knows the other two people of A,B and C and also knows D and E.  So that one person knows every one.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the persons $A,B,C,D,E$ and wlog (without loss of generality) $A,B$ and $C$ are friends (because of your statement and we can rename people in mathematics). Now show, that $D$ and $E$ is befriended with $A,B$ or $C$ and you are finished, since then this person ($A,B$ or $C$) is now friend with everybody (I am sure, you can do this).

Comment: You can't say immediately that $A,B$ and $C$ are all friends. You can say that $A$ and $B$ are both friends with $C$, but from there you cannot infer that $A$ and $B$ are friends.

Comment: Arthur you are right.  But take E and A.  They are both friends with a third.  call that B.  Then A and B are both friends with a third.  Call that C.  So you have A,B,C mutual friends.  (and furthermore E is friends with A and B).